# How to get the main container only in the ECS describe-tasks query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I need to get a list of running ECS tasks with their image names/tags.

Trying in 2 steps:

1. Extracting task ARNs

```
ARNS=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME \
  --desired-status 'RUNNING' --query 'taskArns' \
  --output json --profile $PROFILE)
```

2. Describing tasks

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --tasks $ARNS \
  --profile $PROFILE --output table \
  --query "tasks[] | [].[startedAt,containers[0].image]"
```

The problem is I have multiple sidecar containers in each task, and their order is inconsistent, so `containers[0]` returns a random container every time.

Example output

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                        DescribeTasks                                        |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  2022-08-15T21:01:22.513000-07:00 |  lacework/datacollector:latest-sidecar                  |
|  2022-08-15T21:01:21.511000-07:00 |  lacework/datacollector:latest-sidecar                  |
|  2022-08-15T21:01:22.102000-07:00 |  lacework/datacollector:latest-sidecar                  |
|  2022-08-15T21:01:21.743000-07:00 |  999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:prod  |
|  2022-08-15T21:02:02.298000-07:00 |  999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:prod  |
|  2022-08-15T21:02:31.743000-07:00 |  999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bar:prod  |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Can I filter the list to keep the primary containers only, or at least sort containers in some consistent way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to that is to query the list by images starting with your ECR account ID.

I made it work like this:

```
aws ecs describe-tasks \
--cluster yourClusterName \
--output table \
--query 'tasks[] | [].[startedAt,containers[?starts_with(image, to_string(`999999999999`))].image]' \
--tasks `aws ecs list-tasks --desired-status RUNNING --query taskArns --cluster yourClusterName --output text`
```

Which produces an output like this one:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                DescribeTasks                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2022-10-24T17:29:16.003000+02:00                                          |
|  999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/business:v0.9.1              |
|  2022-10-19T17:53:46.015000+02:00                                          |
|  999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/datacore:v0.5.1              |
|  2022-10-24T17:30:05.670000+02:00                                          |
|  999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/application:v0.16.2          |
|  2022-10-24T18:53:31.795000+02:00                                          |
|  999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/frontend:development-v1.9.7  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I wasn't able to fix the format of the output. JMESPath is not really my thing.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this works as expected, in case all sidecars come from other repos. Strangely it messed up the table columns, their query language made me cry. I'll check it as an accepted answer for now, but may uncheck it in case someone will propose a better solution